# How to Register Keycloak Password Hash Service Provider SPI

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

**Background**

I need to migrate a user database for a bespoke app into Keycloak. I have created a `keycloak-add-user.json` file that imports the users successfully.  Migrated user passwords are hashed in the original system, however I've implemented a Keycloak Password Hash SPI service class that uses the existing algorithm to validate the hash and salt value of a migrated user. The Hash SPI class implements `PasswordHashProviderFactory` and `PasswordHashProvider` from the Keycloak SPI and is based on `Pbkdf2PasswordHashProvider'.

```
public class MyPasswordHashProvider implements PasswordHashProviderFactory, PasswordHashProvider {
public static final String ID = "XXXX";
```

**The issue**

When a migrated user tries to authenticate with keycloak an error is logged by `org.keycloak.hash.PasswordHashManager`

```
Could not find hash provider XXXX for password
```

My jar contains an initialisation file `META-INF/services/org.keycloak.models.PasswordHashProviderFactory` with a single line containing the full classname of the HashProvider implementation.

```
my.folder.MyPasswordHashProvider
```

This was based on the Federation SPI doco, but documentation for the Keycloak Password Hash SPI seems to be non-existent. What am I missing, or what do I need to do to register and use my Hash Provider with Keycloak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a copy/paste error - the initialisation file had the wrong package name 'model' rather than 'hash' and therefore didn't match the `PasswordHashProviderFactory`.

In the provider jar the initialisation file needs to be named:

```
META-INF/services/org.keycloak.credential.hash.PasswordHashProviderFactory
```

and contain a single line with the full name of the implementation factory class - in this case:

```
my.folder.MyPasswordHashProvider
```

Comment: Hi, I also need a custom hash provider. I did the same with you like this but while starting keycloak via `standalone.sh`, errors happened: `Caused by: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: Invalid config for hashAlgorithm: Password hashing provider not found`   So did you ever config anything for `hashAlgorithm`?

Answer (score 2):

In the newer versions of keycloak (I checked 2.5.4), the file needs to be `META-INF/services/org.keycloak.credential.hash.PasswordHashProviderFactory`